What are the 3 different lines running from the street powerline to the fascia board on my house?
There are 3 lines running from the street pole to my house, located in Melbourne Australia. I wanted to confirm the purpose for each one is. I have opinion but needed to be certain. I am looking at getting the facia board repaired or replaced. I would need to have an electrician or other certified tradesman to disconnect them. Which leads me to another question, does any one know what steps to take get a fascia board repaired or replaced due to wood rot in this situation where there is 3 lines connected to it from the street pole, any help is appreciated. Also Ideas & thoughts on what might be the most cost effective option?

Pictures would help. And do you mean 3 wires or 3 cables? (A cable being a group of wires.)

it could be data cables (Phone, TV, Internet) or it it could be power lines.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think  Australia uses just live and neutral(230v).  If power, they should be your live, neutral, and a guide cable to hold the wires up.  The guide should be the only one attached/anchored to the house.
